# Prompt for file in Excel Macro when getting external data from text

Tags: vba, excel, csv, import

We're using an AutoCad utility, CleanupScale 2014, that we want to encourage users to run before using CAD files provided by others in production.  The CSV log file generated by this utility is easiest viewed when imported into Excel by getting external data from text then formatting it.  We'd like to automate as much of this process via a VBA script.

Part of the problem is that the file to import doesn't always have the same file or sheet name.

Can anyone help us with editing the below VBA script so that it will prompt for the CSV file to get the text from before continuing on with the formatting & filtering?

```
Sub ScaleListCleanupLog()
' ScaleListCleanupLog Macro
' Format the Scale List Cleanup Log for easier viewing.

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\User\Documents\CleanupScales48.csv", Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        .Name = "CleanupScales48"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Columns("B:E").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("E1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$24").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        "=Error saving drawing", Operator:=xlOr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right (And I may be completely off) the main problem is returning the path of the CSV that the user selects?

```
Dim myObj As Object
Set myObj = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
myObj.Show
Dim myDirString As String
myDirString = myObj.SelectedItems(1)
MsgBox myDirString
```

The messagebox is just for testing - after this point, the user has selected the file, and you can use myDirString to replace that file path.  Apologies if this isnt what you're looking for

**Edit1:** To answer OP's comment on where to put the code. Added routine to anticipate `Cancel` as well.
 Also I used `msoFileDialogFilePicker` instead of `msoFileDialogOpen` so I can set the `CSV File Filter`.
**Edit2:** Team effort - try this, and see if it runs without errors?  It's the exact same as your original code, but we added the File Dialog browswer which lets a user select a file, then we replaced that hardcoded directory you had with the file directory returned from the File Dialog browser.  This should (might) work without error
**Edit3:**
Just because this is helping me learn a few things too, added one line - "    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & ".domain\Documents"" which should change the default directory

```
 Sub ScaleListCleanupLog()
' ScaleListCleanupLog Macro
' Format the Scale List Cleanup Log for easier viewing.

Dim myObj As Object
Dim myDirString As String

Set myObj = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With myObj
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & ".domain\Documents"
    .Filters.Add "Comma Delimited Files", "*.csv"
    .FilterIndex = 1
    If .Show = False Then MsgBox "Please select CSV file.", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
    myDirString = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & myDirString, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
     .Name = "CleanupScales48"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 1252
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
'rest of the formatting codes here
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Columns("B:E").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Range("E1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$24").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    "=Error saving drawing", Operator:=xlOr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Acantud.  Please forgive my ignorance when it comes to VBA & macros - but where would I add this to my code and/or what text should be replaced?

Comment: @blugirl above also works. To answer your comment I editted Acantud's answer a bit also considering if the user cancels loading.

Comment: @Acantud Hi, I kinda added some info in your answer to answer the OP's comment. I did not add it to my answer which is a different method. Hope it is ok with you ;). Cleat it otherwise. :) Thanks.

Comment: Appreciate the addition L42 that's clearly a much cleaner and safer way to do it.  Bluegirl if you're still working on this problem , insert that code whereever you want- in a module, on a worksheet, though in a module is probably best.  Use l42s suggestion, putting the code in the '~~> rest of the codes here spot, and run it the same way you ran the original macro - or if you're still having trouble comment back

Comment: Hi L42, thanks for the help!  But I'm surely doing something wrong.  Also, in case I didn't clarify, I typically start out with a blank .xlsx file then would like to start the macro to prompt for the .csv file to import & format.  Below is how I added your code.  Please advise as to what I'm squirrelin' up here...

Comment: <code>'
    Dim myObj As Object
Dim myDirString As String

Set myObj = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With myObj
    .Filters.Add "Comma Delimited Files", "*.csv"
    .FilterIndex = 1
    If .Show = False Then MsgBox "Please select CSV file.", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
    myDirString = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & myDirString, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    '~~> rest of the codes here
End With
'rest of the formatting codes here
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False</code>

Comment: Acantud & L42, you guys are brilliant!  That worked absolutely perfectly!  Just a thought/extra request...since by default the CSV file that they need to browse to is always saved at C:\Users\username.domain\Documents, is there a way to have the browse window default to this location regardless of the user name?  We're all on the same domain, but the full path will vary dependent on their user names.

Comment: Made a new quick edit, maybe that will work -  in VBA the command Environ$("Username") returns the username, and in that file dialog browser adding a ".initialfilename" property lets you set what folder it will start it.  So I set it to concact (Using the & symbols) a directory like you specified.  If it errors out you can tweak that line - on my pc my My Documents folder is C:\Users\MyFirst.MyLast\Documents , it doesnt have '.domain' on the end.  Hope that helps

Comment: Acantud, that works absolutely perfectly!  Thanks to you & L42 to for making my 1st experience on this site beyond awesome!

Comment: Super happy to help - don't forget to contribute once you get the hang of this stuff!  Have a great one

Comment: Will do, Acantud!  Thanks & you too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim myfile

myfile = Application.GetOpenFileName("Comma Delimited Files, *.csv")

If myfile <> False Then

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & myfile, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        '~~> rest of your code here
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Please select CSV file.", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
End If
'~~>Then your formatting codes here
```

Hope this helps.